# AB Test For Ecommerce Coupon Promotion

Tags: t-test, ab-test

I'd like to run A/B Test for Ecommerce Coupon Promotion.

1. Random Sampling from Total User Group.
2. Random Grouping into Experimental(Give Coupon) / Control (Don't Give Coupon) 9:1 ratio

Situation likes below :

|  | Num of User | Num of User who Orderd | Total Sales Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Experimental | 90,000(90%) | 5,500 | 15,500,000 |
| Control | 9,000(10%) | 500 | 1,500,000 |

It is obvious that Order Rate is Increased. (6.1% vs 5.5%)

But My Interest is Total Sales Price Per User.

In this Case
Experimental 15,500,000 / 90,000 = 172.2 
Control       1,500,000 /  9,000 = 166.6
[Total User]

or 
Experimental 15,500,000 / 5,500 = 2818.2
Control       1,500,000 /   500 = 3000.0
[Ordered User]

which Metric Should be tested ?

+) If in Experimental Group, Last Week Orderd User is 4,000(May be 500 is same with Ordered in this Promotion) and Their Total Sales Price is 10,800,000 ( 10,800,000 / 4,000 = 2,700 )

If then, It is possible to say that In experimental Group, Total Sales Price / User (Maybe RPU?) is Increased 118(2818 - 2700) Due to Coupon ?
I think It is not appropriate to compare Total Sales Price / User in Last Week and Promotion Week as their Denominator User (4,000 and 5,500) is Not Same.

I'd like to check the effect of Promotion related to Sales Price(Not a Conversion Rate, I'd like to check that Revenue is increased due to Promotion). Is there any other Metric ?

Thanks.

Comment: As the Promotion, Total Sales Price is absolutely Increasd(In My Real Numbers...)
And Sales Price Per User in Decreased.

It could be possible due to Some of User Ordered Only Small Amount to use Coupon .
My Coworker says that As we gave Coupon Sales Price Per User decreased(It is Fact.) and If We didn't give coupon, Users would have paid more... (Is It Right...?)